# Concatenate Numbers in sqlite as text with a dash character

Tags: string, sqlite, casting, concatenation, varchar

I am trying to concatenate numbers as text, with a dash (`-`) between the numbers I am concatenating.

I have figured out how to concatenate numbers as text:

```
CAST(variable1 AS VARCAHR) || CAST(variable2 AS VARCHAR)
```

I would like a dash between these, i.e.

```
CAST(variable1 AS VARCAHR) || CAST(- AS VARCHAR) || CAST(variable2 AS VARCHAR)
```

but this gives me an invalid SQL error.  I think it might have something to do with the dash not being in unicode or something, I am not sure.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: And to whoever did the -1, I spent like 2 hours trying to figure this out.  The answer just wasn't obvious to someone newer at sqlite.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just concat it with a literal string (also you don't need the casts):

```
variable1 || '-' || variable2
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. If you don't have CAST then the numbers won't appear.

Comment: @AlexB You don't need the cast if the variables are actually numbers. I suspect you actually have empty strings or `NULL`s. `SELECT 1.0 || '-' || 2.0;` works fine for me.

Answer (score 8):

This answer above that got 4 votes is wrong. Without CAST then the numeric value will not appear.

The correct answer is:

```
CAST(variable1 AS VARCHAR)|| '-' ||  variable2
```

Comment: I just did a similar concat in SQLITE without using cast and it worked ok. it was like NUMERIC_FIELD || CHAR_FIELD