# How to store a dataframe in sqlite3 with a uniqueid for each row

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'm working with a `.csv` dataset that I got from [here](https://github.com/alanjones2/dataviz/raw/master/londonweather.csv).

I managed to write the code below to store the dataframe `weather` in a sql database/table but I don't know how to create a unique ID (eg. OID1, OID2, ...) in the database/table for each row.

##### CODE :

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import pandas as pd

weather = pd.read_csv('londonweather.csv', delimiter=',')
conn = sql.connect('weather.db')
weather.to_sql('weather', conn)
```

##### >>> `weather.sample(5)`

[image]

Also, whenever I update the dataframe (by adding some rows), these rows have to be inserted in the database/table with a unique ID **(OIDx, with x as the row index in the table)**.

Is it possible to achieve this ? Do you have any propositions, please ?

Comment: (year, month) - your unique (composite) id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and thanks to the SO posts/answers below, I managed to build the right code for my question :

1. [How to correctly set AUTO INCREMENT fo a column in SQLite, using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26652736/19603419)
2. [Concatenating a string and primary key Id while inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23331246/19603419)
3. [Concatenate Numbers in sqlite as text with a dash character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31525964/19603419)

###### 1 - How to store the dataframe in the database :

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import pandas as pd

### --- READING THE CSV AS A DATAFRAME
df = pd.read_csv('londonweather.csv', delimiter=',')

### --- CREATING THE DATABASE + CURSOR
conn = sql.connect('weather_SO.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

### --- CREATING THE TABLE
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WEATHER_TABLE
           (unique_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Year INTEGER, Month INTEGER, Tmax REAL, Tmin REAL, Rain REAL, Sun REAL)''')

### --- COPYING THE DATAFRAME TO THE TABLE
df.to_sql('WEATHER_TABLE', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

###### 2 - How to create a unique ID (OIDx) :

```
### --- UPDATING THE VALUE OF THE UNIQUE ID
cur.execute("UPDATE WEATHER_TABLE set unique_id = 'OID' || rowid")

### --- SAVING CHANGES
conn.commit()
```

###### 3 - How to insert multiple new elements/rows :

```
### --- INSERTING NEW ROWS THE TABLE
data_weather = [(2022, 7, 20.0, 20.0, 1.0, 2.0), (2022, 8, 19.3, 20.0, 2.0, 8.0)]
cur.executemany('INSERT INTO WEATHER_TABLE(Year, Month, Tmax, Tmin, Rain, Sun) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)', data_weather)

### --- UPDATING THE UNIQUE ID OF THE NEW ROWS
conn.execute("UPDATE WEATHER_TABLE set unique_id = 'OID' || rowid")

### --- SAVING CHANGES AND CLOSING CONNECTION
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

###### RESULT (in SQLiteStudio), showing the last five rows :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import pandas as pd

weather = pd.read_csv("weather.csv", delimiter=",")
conn = sql.connect("weather.db")

weather["OID"] = list(map(lambda x: "OID" + str(int(x)), weather.index))

print(weather.head())
```

output:

```
   Year  Month  Tmax  Tmin  Rain    Sun   OID
0  1957      1   8.7   2.7  39.5   53.0  OID0
1  1957      2   9.0   2.9  69.8   64.9  OID1
2  1957      3  13.9   5.7  25.4   96.7  OID2
3  1957      4  14.2   5.2   5.7  169.6  OID3
4  1957      5  16.2   6.5  21.3  195.0  OID4
```

rest of the code:

```
schema = pd.io.json.build_table_schema(weather, primary_key="OID")
weather.to_sql("weather", conn, schema)

print(conn.execute("SELECT * FROM weather").fetchone())
```

output:

```
(0, 1957, 1, 8.7, 2.7, 39.5, 53.0, 'OID0')
```

If you want to add the OID to new rows execute this line again:

```
weather["OID"] = list(map(lambda x: "OID" + str(int(x)), weather.index))
```

Just make sure you don't change the index of any of the rows

Comment: Hi @itogaston, thank you for the contribution. I'm looking for a unique ID that has the format described in my post (OIDx, with x as the row index in the table). Since OIDx has to be auto-incremented, I think that it has to be managed by sqlite3 (the database itself) and not pandas.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite creates ROWID for you, unless you specifically instructed it not to do so.

Comment: Hi @PChemGuy, when I open the database in SQLiteStudio, I don't see this ROWID. How can we specify to sqlite to create that column and also add the prefix 'OID' ? I can see only pandas index (starting from 0) as the first column.

Comment: This column is created and called ROWID or _ROWID_. In SQLite Studio, you have to run a query "SELECT ROWID, * FROM weather" to see it. In "DB Browser for SQLite", you can request the GUI to show ROWID.

Comment: All right, I run `select rowid from weather` and I got the rowid column. How can we now create this unique ID column ? Don't forget that the dataframe will we updated after the first creation of the table.

Comment: This column IS CREATED already. https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html

Comment: Do you need to import multiple CSV's repeatedly? Otherwise, why not using the SQLite shell for importing the CSV directly into your database?

Comment: What is the point of `weather["OID"] = list(map(lambda x: "OID" + str(int(x)), weather.index))`? This is not going to work! You should never do things like that anyway! And do not store integer PKs as text. This is not a good idea either.